# Sequelize ModelNotInitializedError: Model not initialized

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to instantiate a new object of my Product model in my service but I got error:
`

```
ModelNotInitializedError: Model not initialized: Product cannot be instantiated. "Product" needs to be added to a Sequelize instance.
```

`

There is my sequelize config
I'm ussing repository mode and build the path that contain my models.

```
import { join } from "path";
import { Config } from "sequelize";
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize-typescript";

const path = join(__dirname, '..', '/entities/models/*.model.ts')

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  repositoryMode: true,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
  schema: 'store',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: '123.',
  models: [path],
  modelMatch: (filename, member) => {
    return filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf('.model')).toLowerCase() === member.toLowerCase();
  },
  hooks: {
    afterConnect: async (connection: Sequelize, _config: Config) => {
      try {
        await connection.query('set search_path = store')
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error at set search path: ', error)
      }
    }
  }
})

export { sequelize }
```

There are my classes.
Product model, this model I attemp to instantiate.

```
import { Table, Column, Model, BelongsToMany } from 'sequelize-typescript'
import { Category, CategoryProduct } from './index'

@Table({
  timestamps: false,
  modelName: 'tal_product',
  freezeTableName: true,
  underscored: true
})
export class Product extends Model {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true })
  id!: number

  @Column
  name!: string

  @Column
  stock!: number

  @Column({ field: 'is_active' })
  isActive?: boolean

  @BelongsToMany(() => Category, () => CategoryProduct)
  categories?: Category[]
}
```

Product repository, here I have all my querys.

```
import { Repository } from 'sequelize-typescript'
import { Category, Product } from '../../../entities/models'
import { sequelize } from '../adminModule'
import { ProductRepository } from './product.repository'

export class ProductRepositoryImp implements ProductRepository {
  productRepository: Repository<Product>
  categoryRepository: Repository<Category>

  constructor() {
    this.productRepository = sequelize.getRepository(Product)
    this.categoryRepository = sequelize.getRepository(Category)
  }
  
  create = async (product: Product): Promise<Product> => {
    return await this.productRepository.create({ ...product })
  }
}
```

product service, here I call the producRepository and instantiate my model

```
import { ICreateProduct, IProduct } from '../../../dto/product.dto'
import { Product } from '../../../entities/models'
import { ProductRepository } from '../repositories'
import { ProductServices } from './product.services'

export class ProductServicesImp implements ProductServices {
  private productRepository: ProductRepository

  public constructor(productRepository: ProductRepository) {
    this.productRepository = productRepository
  }
  
  create = async (productDto: ICreateProduct): Promise<IProduct> => {
    const product = new Product()
    product.name = productDto.name
    product.stock = productDto.stock

    return await this.productRepository.create(product)
  }
}
```

In ProductServicesImp when I instantiate a 'new Product()' I got the error.

Comment: Did you check if any model files were passed to `modelMatch`?

Comment: Yes! all model files are ok! I have src/entities/models/product.model.ts

Comment: And modelMatch returns `true` for all of them?

Comment: Yes returns 'true' for all of them

Comment: Did you check `models` prop of the Sequelize instance?

Comment: What do you mean? I have other query for find all products and it works fine

Comment: I mean you need to make sure you have `Product` model in this `models` prop and it should be strictly equal to `Product` you imported from '../../../entities/models'

Comment: Oh ok, yes I'm pretty sure they are the same models. I tried directly importing the model in 'models' props and got the same error :(

Comment: Did you try to turn off the repository mode and use a direct models's methods?

Comment: Oh, with 'repository mode' disabled, I can instantiate a new product...why?

Comment: Seems like you can't instantiate in repository mode because it does it every time you get a repository. So you just need to pass an arbitrary object to `create` and that's all

Comment: Oh ok thank you! I will pass an interface 'ICreateProduct' to create.